# Null Length Error on Craft Version 3

Tags: templating, craft3

I am not super fluent in Twig and I inherited a website from a company that built the site in Craft v2. The site was upgraded to version 3 of Craft recently and one of the template pages is throwing an error where on version 2 of Craft it was not. Code:

```
{% set faqs = craft.entries.section('FAQ').search('slug::' ~ entry.slug).first() %}

{% if faqs.questionsanswers|length > 0 %}
  <a href="#link">FAQs</a>
{% endif %}
```

This is throwing an error: `Impossible to access an attribute ("questionsanswers") on a null variable.`

So since it was returning `null` I changed the code to this which seems to be working:

```
{% if faqs is not null and faqs is not empty %}
  <a href="#link">FAQs</a>
{% endif %}
```

My question is why would this code not work for version 3 when it was working correctly for version 2? Why would the length return `null` instead of `0`? I did not do the upgrade but maybe something was missed? (This is a template page and some of the entries do have FAQs and some don't) Or perhaps something with the structure of the version 3 of Craft has changed? Lastly if there is a better way to do/code what is being done I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error tells you that `faqs` is `null`. As you're using the `first()` function to execute your element query, this means that your query has no matches.

1. Are you sure that the section handle (`FAQ`) is in uppercase?
2. The correct way to create an entry query in Craft 3 is `craft.entries()`. Although it may work without the parenthesis, it can't hurt to add them.
3. You can replace `.search('slug::' ~ entry.slug)`  with `.slug(entry.slug)`. It's easier to understand and should have the same effect.
4. Are you sure that the query always returned something in Craft 2? It may be worth adding a null check to avoid the error: `{% if faqs and faqs.questionsanswers and faqs.questionsanswers|length > 0 %}`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, your insight is very helpful and I have already used some of your suggestions to help better format the code.